# Best approach to make all tags searchable by the wordpress search function

Tags: plugins, custom-field, search, tags

I have over 2000 tags on one of my sites and I like them to be searchable by the wordpress search function.

The problem is if I use a plugin, the time it takes to search them all is enormous.

I think on a possible solution that would be to add them (post tags) all inside a custom field and use a plugin to make it search on that custom field on all posts.

But as I'm not a great expert in wordpress I would like to have a more endorsed opinion.

What do you think?

Comment: I remeber a hack I used long time ago for a site that was not updated much to auto add the tags as a html comment into the post content after post update. This made the tags searchable for free and no extra table joins but this kind of hack is absolute not suitable for all sites :)

Comment: In html comment I presume that would add them to the code. Maybe I was not 100% clear at my question... Sorry... But how can that make the tags searchable on wordpress search function?

Comment: The built in search looks into the post content field by default, but this was just a hack I remembered :-) The more information you add to the question the more likely it will help others suggesting a suitable solution.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but it can have a downside if displayed twice (in the post and in the code) as it can be seen as duplicate content in the eyes of search engines.

I hadn't thought of this hack. But also for SEO reasons, saving the tags in a custom field and making it available only for the native wordpress search function seems better to me.

Nevertheless, I'd like more opinions because I'm not sure what the implications are in terms of performance.

Comment: ps: it should be possible to strip it out with a filter on the frontend if needed.  Custom fields searches in WP_Query are in general not that good for performance.

Comment: That's also a great point of view. I wish to digg deeper into this discussion. Hopefully this question will have some impact and receptivity among the people more in tune with Wordpress. Cheers!